# Issue on type in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is content of height variable be a String or a number?By subtraction variable k from height appear a Nan error.

```
var k=761; 
var height = $('#dornierenvoj img').css('height');
console.log(height - k);
```

Comment: Did you try to look at what was in `height` ? You should have before asking SO. See [Using the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Comment: It is not an integer?uhmmm maybe a string

Comment: Just look, don't guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to substract an int from a string. You must use

```
.replace('px', '');
```

in order to get a number, and then do the math operations.

http://jsfiddle.net/hyZu4/